# perl win32 ole timeout

Tags: perl, excel, winapi, ole

I use perl and Win32::OLE to automate some Excel task. Because of the Excel file too big, thus the process takes quite amount of time to finish... But after leaving it overnight, I believe it gets stuck because of "timeout" problem. If I reduce the file size then it's OK.

Anyway to increase the timeout??

Portion of my code:

```
#   Open the rules file
my $xlBook = $xlApp->Workbooks->Open("$file");
my $xlSheet = $xlBook->Worksheets(1);

#Replace FALSE -> 0
$xlSheet->Cells->Replace ({ What => "FALSE", Replacement => "0" });
#Replace TRUE -> 1
$xlSheet->Cells->Replace ({ What => "TRUE", Replacement => "1" });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to change the automation timeout is to call [CoRegisterMessageFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693324%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to register your [IMessageFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693740%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) implementation to handle COM calls, say, [call OLEUIBusy to display a server busy dialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694352%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I don't think Win32::OLE implements this, you can try wrap the CoRegisterMessageFilter code in an in-process COM server and register the message filter in the server.